# Parse value to a mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this quick question, i have got the username variable from a form and i need to insert it in a query, can you please tell me where i'm going wrong, it says: Unknown column '$username' in 'field list'

Here is the code:

```
echo $HTTP_POST_VARS['username'];

   echo $username;
   $query = sprintf( 'SELECT $username FROM hostess' );
```

Comment: Don't do this. STOP. Read up and learn about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) before you go ANY farther with this kind of coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhmm about everything seems wrong..

First of all, you never defined the variable $username.
What you are doing would only be valid in a version of PHP that still supports suberglobals.

Second, why are you using sprintf for a query?

By the way, HTTP_POST_VARS is deprecated. Use POST

Correct code would be something like this;

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];
echo $username;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT ".$username." FROM hostess");
```

Comment: Good to hear! Could you mark my answer as the correct one? Thanks

Comment: Sure, i just need to wait 4 more minutes to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

1. In the code supplied you never set `$username`.
2. You're wide open for [Sql injection](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5DP0N1P76E.html).
3. You're using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) without any reason - it formats a string but you're not supplying any formatting, my example below does
4. You're trying to `'SELECT $username FROM hostess'` but that's not a valid Sql statement at all.

You'd be wanting something more like:

```
$query = sprintf( "SELECT * FROM hostess WHERE username='%s'", $username);
```

AFTER making sure you clean $username.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = sprintf( 'SELECT %s FROM hostess', $username);
```

-or, if that's a string value, I suspect you may want to include that in single quotes in the query text -

```
$query = sprintf( "SELECT '%s' FROM hostess", $username);
```

NOTE: The generated SQL statement looks a bit odd, in that its going to return the same literal value for every row in the hostess table.  If there's a hundred rows in the hostess table, you are going to return 100 rows with the same literal value. This may be what you want, but it strikes me as VERY odd.

NOTE: The sprintf function looks for %s, %d, etc. placeholders in the first argument, and replaces them with values from the remaining arguments.)

NOTE: If `$username` contains a value coming in from a form, and has not been validated, to thwart SQL injection attacks, I would use the (admittedly old school)  `mysql_real_escape_string` function. (Others will offer suggestions for better, more modern techniques to accomplish the same result.)

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT '%s' FROM hostess",mysql_real_escape_string($username));
```

Comment: Hey thanks, is it normal that the output is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM hostess' at line 1

I'm on localhost..

Comment: @Gazeta Almedicus:  If the query text is malformed, yes, it is expected.  If $username contains an integer value, it should not be a problem.  "SELECT 1 FROM hostess".  If $username is a string, then it may be a problem if $username is not a valid SQL expression...

Answer (score 0):

in PHP, using the single quote for strings will not parse the string for variables. Use either concatenation or double quotes:

```
$query = sprintf( 'SELECT ' . $username . ' FROM hostess' );
$query = sprintf( "SELECT $username FROM hostess");
```

Of course, this is to say nothing about the terrible risks using a POST var this way implies.